# Angular click event triggers on entire component in recursive nested component

Tags: angular

I have 2 components - list view component detail component. The detail component is being rendered recursively and has a click handler.

**List View Component**

HTML:

```
<app-basket-item-detail *ngFor="let rootBasketItem of rootBasketItems$ | async"
                        [basketItemId]="rootBasketItem.basketItemId"
                        [basketItems]="allBasketItems$ | async"
                        [offeringsCache]="offeringsCache$ | async"
                        (removeBasketItem)="removeBasketItem($event)">
</app-basket-item-detail>
```

Code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-basket-item-list-view',
  templateUrl: './basket-item-list-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./basket-item-list-view.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class BasketItemListViewComponent {
  rootBasketItems$: Observable<Array<BasketItem>>;
  allBasketItems$: Observable<Array<BasketItem>>;
  offeringsCache$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
    this.rootBasketItems$ = store.select(fromRoot.getRootBasketItems);
    this.allBasketItems$ = store.select(fromRoot.getBasketItemsMap);
    this.offeringsCache$ = store.select(fromRoot.getOfferingsCache);
  }

  removeBasketItem(basketItem) {
    this.store.dispatch(new basketActions.RemoveBasketItem(basketItem));
  }
}
```

**Detail Component (recursive detail component)**

HTML:

```
<ul class="basket-item-list">
  <li class="basket-item-action justify-content-between" [ngClass]="basketItem?.action.toLowerCase()">
    <span>{{ offeringsCache[basketItemId]?.description }}</span>
    <button class="close" (click)="removeBasketItem.emit(basketItem)">
      <span>&times;</span>
    </button>
  </li>

  <app-basket-item-detail *ngFor="let childBasketItemId of basketItem.children"
                          [basketItemId]="childBasketItemId"
                          [basketItems]="basketItems"
                          [offeringsCache]="offeringsCache"
                          (click)="removeBasketItem.emit(basketItems[childBasketItemId])">
  </app-basket-item-detail>
</ul>
```

Code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-basket-item-detail',
  templateUrl: './basket-item-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./basket-item-detail.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class BasketItemDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() basketItemId: string;
  @Input() basketItems: Array<BasketItem> = [];
  @Input() offeringsCache: [string, BasketItem] = [undefined, undefined];

  @Output() removeBasketItem = new EventEmitter<BasketItem>();

  basketItem: BasketItem;
  offering: ProductOffering;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.basketItem = this.basketItems[this.basketItemId];
    this.offering = this.offeringsCache[this.basketItemId];
  }

}
```

**Problem**

The view where the list is rendered looks like this:
[image: Basket View]

What is giving me a headache is that the click event is also triggering not only when I click the X, but it also triggers when I click on the `li` element. Is there a cure for that? I have been trying everything I can think of to stop it from behaving like that. I want the click events only be handled by the button.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, you have `(click)="removeBasketItem.emit(basketItems[childBasketItemId])"` on the detail component. If you don't want the component clickable, why do you have that?

Answer (score 3):

You might need to stop propagation. The click event is bubbling:

```
(click)="removeBasketItem.emit(basketItem);$event.stopPropagation()"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this onclick handler in your `app-basket-item-detail` component: `(click)="removeBasketItem.emit(basketItems[childBasketItemId])"`.

With this, all recursively created components will have an onclick on the complete component. I don't think it is necessary, because the nested component itself will have a new onclick listener on its own button. Try removing it.

Comment: Right. Completely overlook that, I see the cause, but removing it doesn't give me the desired behavior, because the initial detail component is looped over `rootBasketItems$` and the child components over the children from another array and with current solution only the root items would get the button click handler. Would need to find another solution here.

Comment: Instead of a onclick listener, you could have an isDeleted event that is emitted to the parent which then handles the deletion in the children array.